# 'groupby.quantile' can't take an array-like as argument?

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I'm trying to compute multiple percentiles on a certain column of my dataframe, however when I pass a list of percentiles as an argument my program falls apart. I found a turn around to this problem using a 'for' loop but I assume it's way slower than passing a list directly to the quantile() method.

How can I make these calculations faster ?

Here's a reproducible example: (Note that I had to define a Quantile function otherwise aggregating with it directly won't work)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime 
import random

Timer_S = time.time()
class Quantile:
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q
        
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x.quantile(self.q, interpolation= 'lower')

new_order = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'] 
Percentiles = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10**5, freq="1H")})
df['Rand'] = np.random.randint(0, 10, df.shape[0])
list_P = []

Quantiles_df = df.copy()    
Quantiles_df['Month'] = Quantiles_df['Start'].dt.strftime('%B')

for element in Percentiles:
  k = Quantiles_df.groupby(['Month']).agg({'Rand' : Quantile(element)})
  k = k.reindex(new_order,axis = 0)
  list_P.append(k) 

Final_df = pd.concat(list_P , axis=1)
Final_df.columns = [f'P_{int(element*100)}' for element in Percentiles]

Timer_E = time.time()
display(Final_df)
print(f'Quantile timer : {Timer_E - Timer_S} secs')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead of looping? First `groupby` and `agg` using multiple `quantiles`. Then `pivot_table` to unstack the results.

```
pd.pivot_table(Quantiles_df.groupby("Month").quantile([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]).reset_index()
               , index='Month', columns='level_1').reset_index().droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
```

I got this

```
level_1         0.1     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.5     0.6
0   April   0.0     1.0     2.0     4.0     5.0     5.0
1   August  0.0     2.0     2.0     4.0     5.0     6.0
2   December    0.0     1.0     3.0     4.0     4.5     6.0
3   February    1.0     2.0     3.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
4   January     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0
5   July    0.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     4.0     5.0
6   June    1.0     1.0     3.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
7   March   0.0     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
8   May     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0
9   November    0.9     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     5.0
10  October     0.0     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     6.0
11  September   0.0     1.0     2.0     4.0     5.0     6.0
```